# How to hide the android status bar when using phonegap builtin browser

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

i am using phonegap 3.0 and the built in inapbrowser.

```
<a href="#" ontouchstart="window.open('http://www.google.de/', '_blank', 'location=no')">Google</a>
```

there is no url bar but the android status bar. i want it to be fullscreen, without the status bar that shows clock etc.

How do i hide the status bar when opening the inappbrowser?

Comment: Actually Inapp browser is a Dialog view

Comment: not sure you can do it with phonegap. Other than building an interface in `Java` to toggle fullscreen of your app and calling it from Cordova